# entity framework query and performance

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a Project Like social Network 
I have to write a query to get some  posts and last comment of post  that my followers (not blocked) liked That 
my code

```
public List<PostProject> GetFavoritePosts(string userId, int currentPage, int noOfRecords)
    {
        var skipPosts = noOfRecords * currentPage;
        int i = -260;
        var day = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);

        var blockedusers = DataContext.BlockedUsers.Where(bu => bu.BlockerId == userId);
        var followers = DataContext.FollowUser.Where(u => u.FollowFromUserId == userId);
        var posts = DataContext.Posts.Where(p => p.UserId != userId
        && p.DateOfUpdate > day
        && p.Likes.Any(l => followers.Any(fu => fu.FollowToUserId == l.UserId))
        && p.PostStatusId == 1
        && p.PostType == false
        && blockedusers.All(bu => bu.BlockedId != p.UserId));

        var feed = posts

            .OrderByDescending(post => post.Likes.Count)
            .Select(post => new PostProject
            {
                PostId = post.PostId,
                Content = post.Content,
                Image = post.Image,
                Location = post.Location,
                Video = post.Video,
                CreatedDate = post.CreatedDate,
                DateOfUpdate = post.DateOfUpdate,
                User = post.User,
                ILiked = post.Likes.Any(like => like.UserId == userId),
                LikeCount = post.Likes.Count,
                CommentsCount = post.Comments.Count,
                PostStatusId = post.PostStatusId,
                ShareCount = post.SharePosts.Count,
                Comments = new List<Comment> { post.Comments.OrderByDescending(c =>   c.CommentDate).FirstOrDefault() }
            });
        return feed.Skip(() => skipPosts).Take(() => noOfRecords).ToList();
    }
```

This code generate sqlQuery with 16 select   and 50ms to run !!!!

Where is my mistake 
thanks

sql Query :

```
SELECT 
[Project13].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
[Project13].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
[Project13].[Content] AS [Content], 
[Project13].[Image] AS [Image], 
[Project13].[Location] AS [Location], 
[Project13].[Video] AS [Video], 
[Project13].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
[Project13].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
[Project13].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project13].[VisualId] AS [VisualId], 
[Project13].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
[Project13].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
[Project13].[Activated] AS [Activated], 
[Project13].[ActivationCode] AS [ActivationCode], 
[Project13].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
[Project13].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
[Project13].[RegisterToken] AS [RegisterToken], 
[Project13].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Project13].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
[Project13].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
[Project13].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
[Project13].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
[Project13].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
[Project13].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
[Project13].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
[Project13].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
[Project13].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
[Project13].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Project13].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project13].[C4] AS [C2], 
[Project13].[C5] AS [C3], 
[Project13].[C6] AS [C4], 
[Project13].[C2] AS [C5], 
[Project13].[CommentId] AS [CommentId], 
[Project13].[CommentText] AS [CommentText], 
[Project13].[PostId1] AS [PostId1], 
[Project13].[CommentDate] AS [CommentDate], 
[Project13].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Project13].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project11].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
    [Project11].[Content] AS [Content], 
    [Project11].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
    [Project11].[Image] AS [Image], 
    [Project11].[Location] AS [Location], 
    [Project11].[Video] AS [Video], 
    [Project11].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
    [Project11].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
    [Project11].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project11].[VisualId] AS [VisualId], 
    [Project11].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
    [Project11].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
    [Project11].[Activated] AS [Activated], 
    [Project11].[ActivationCode] AS [ActivationCode], 
    [Project11].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
    [Project11].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
    [Project11].[RegisterToken] AS [RegisterToken], 
    [Project11].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Project11].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Project11].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Project11].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Project11].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Project11].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Project11].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Project11].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Project11].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Project11].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Project11].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Project11].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit1].[CommentId] AS [CommentId], 
    [Limit1].[CommentText] AS [CommentText], 
    [Limit1].[PostId] AS [PostId1], 
    [Limit1].[CommentDate] AS [CommentDate], 
    [Limit1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Limit1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    1 AS [C2], 
    [Project11].[C2] AS [C3], 
    [Project11].[C3] AS [C4], 
    [Project11].[C4] AS [C5], 
    [Project11].[C5] AS [C6]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Project9].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
        [Project9].[Content] AS [Content], 
        [Project9].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
        [Project9].[Image] AS [Image], 
        [Project9].[Location] AS [Location], 
        [Project9].[Video] AS [Video], 
        [Project9].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
        [Project9].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
        [Project9].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project9].[VisualId] AS [VisualId], 
        [Project9].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
        [Project9].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
        [Project9].[Activated] AS [Activated], 
        [Project9].[ActivationCode] AS [ActivationCode], 
        [Project9].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
        [Project9].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
        [Project9].[RegisterToken] AS [RegisterToken], 
        [Project9].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Project9].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
        [Project9].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
        [Project9].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
        [Project9].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
        [Project9].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
        [Project9].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
        [Project9].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
        [Project9].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
        [Project9].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
        [Project9].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
        CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Likes] AS [Extent10]
            WHERE ([Project9].[PostId] = [Extent10].[PostId]) AND (([Extent10].[UserId] = @p__linq__4) OR (([Extent10].[UserId] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__4 IS NULL)))
        )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1], 
        [Project9].[C1] AS [C2], 
        [Project9].[C2] AS [C3], 
        [Project9].[C3] AS [C4], 
        [Project9].[C4] AS [C5]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project8].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
            [Project8].[Content] AS [Content], 
            [Project8].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
            [Project8].[Image] AS [Image], 
            [Project8].[Location] AS [Location], 
            [Project8].[Video] AS [Video], 
            [Project8].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
            [Project8].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
            [Project8].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project8].[VisualId] AS [VisualId], 
            [Project8].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
            [Project8].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
            [Project8].[Activated] AS [Activated], 
            [Project8].[ActivationCode] AS [ActivationCode], 
            [Project8].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
            [Project8].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
            [Project8].[RegisterToken] AS [RegisterToken], 
            [Project8].[Email] AS [Email], 
            [Project8].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
            [Project8].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
            [Project8].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
            [Project8].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
            [Project8].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
            [Project8].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
            [Project8].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
            [Project8].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
            [Project8].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
            [Project8].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
            [Project8].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project8].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project8].[C3] AS [C3], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[SharePosts] AS [Extent9]
                WHERE [Project8].[PostId] = [Extent9].[PostId]) AS [C4]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project7].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
                [Project7].[Content] AS [Content], 
                [Project7].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
                [Project7].[Image] AS [Image], 
                [Project7].[Location] AS [Location], 
                [Project7].[Video] AS [Video], 
                [Project7].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
                [Project7].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
                [Project7].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project7].[VisualId] AS [VisualId], 
                [Project7].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
                [Project7].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
                [Project7].[Activated] AS [Activated], 
                [Project7].[ActivationCode] AS [ActivationCode], 
                [Project7].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
                [Project7].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
                [Project7].[RegisterToken] AS [RegisterToken], 
                [Project7].[Email] AS [Email], 
                [Project7].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
                [Project7].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
                [Project7].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
                [Project7].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
                [Project7].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
                [Project7].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
                [Project7].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
                [Project7].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
                [Project7].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
                [Project7].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                [Project7].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project7].[C2] AS [C2], 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent8]
                    WHERE [Project7].[PostId] = [Extent8].[PostId]) AS [C3]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project6].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
                    [Project6].[Content] AS [Content], 
                    [Project6].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
                    [Project6].[Image] AS [Image], 
                    [Project6].[Location] AS [Location], 
                    [Project6].[Video] AS [Video], 
                    [Project6].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
                    [Project6].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
                    [Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Project6].[VisualId] AS [VisualId], 
                    [Project6].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
                    [Project6].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
                    [Project6].[Activated] AS [Activated], 
                    [Project6].[ActivationCode] AS [ActivationCode], 
                    [Project6].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
                    [Project6].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
                    [Project6].[RegisterToken] AS [RegisterToken], 
                    [Project6].[Email] AS [Email], 
                    [Project6].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
                    [Project6].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
                    [Project6].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
                    [Project6].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
                    [Project6].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
                    [Project6].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
                    [Project6].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
                    [Project6].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
                    [Project6].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
                    [Project6].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                    [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM [dbo].[Likes] AS [Extent7]
                        WHERE [Project6].[PostId] = [Extent7].[PostId]) AS [C2]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project5].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
                        [Project5].[Content] AS [Content], 
                        [Project5].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
                        [Project5].[Image] AS [Image], 
                        [Project5].[Location] AS [Location], 
                        [Project5].[Video] AS [Video], 
                        [Project5].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
                        [Project5].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
                        [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        [Extent6].[VisualId] AS [VisualId], 
                        [Extent6].[ProfilePicUrl] AS [ProfilePicUrl], 
                        [Extent6].[DateCreated] AS [DateCreated], 
                        [Extent6].[Activated] AS [Activated], 
                        [Extent6].[ActivationCode] AS [ActivationCode], 
                        [Extent6].[RoleId] AS [RoleId], 
                        [Extent6].[TeamId] AS [TeamId], 
                        [Extent6].[RegisterToken] AS [RegisterToken], 
                        [Extent6].[Email] AS [Email], 
                        [Extent6].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
                        [Extent6].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
                        [Extent6].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
                        [Extent6].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
                        [Extent6].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
                        [Extent6].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
                        [Extent6].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
                        [Extent6].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
                        [Extent6].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
                        [Extent6].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
                        [Project5].[C1] AS [C1]
                        FROM   (SELECT 
                            [Extent1].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
                            [Extent1].[Content] AS [Content], 
                            [Extent1].[PostStatusId] AS [PostStatusId], 
                            [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
                            [Extent1].[Image] AS [Image], 
                            [Extent1].[Location] AS [Location], 
                            [Extent1].[Video] AS [Video], 
                            [Extent1].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
                            [Extent1].[DateOfUpdate] AS [DateOfUpdate], 
                            (SELECT 
                                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                FROM [dbo].[Likes] AS [Extent5]
                                WHERE [Extent1].[PostId] = [Extent5].[PostId]) AS [C1]
                            FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
                            WHERE ( NOT (([Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 = (CASE WHEN (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))) AND ([Extent1].[DateOfUpdate] > @p__linq__1) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
                                1 AS [C1]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId]
                                    FROM [dbo].[Likes] AS [Extent2]
                                    WHERE [Extent1].[PostId] = [Extent2].[PostId]
                                )  AS [Project1]
                                WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
                                    1 AS [C1]
                                    FROM [dbo].[FollowUsers] AS [Extent3]
                                    WHERE ([Extent3].[FollowFromUserId] = @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent3].[FollowToUserId] = [Project1].[UserId])
                                )
                            )) AND (1 = [Extent1].[PostStatusId]) AND (0 = [Extent1].[PostType]) AND ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                                1 AS [C1]
                                FROM [dbo].[BlockedUsers] AS [Extent4]
                                WHERE ([Extent4].[BlockerId] = @p__linq__3) AND (([Extent4].[BlockedId] = [Extent1].[UserId]) OR (CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[BlockedId] <> [Extent1].[UserId]) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ([Extent4].[BlockedId] = [Extent1].[UserId]) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL))
                            )) ) AS [Project5]
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent6] ON [Project5].[UserId] = [Extent6].[Id]
                    )  AS [Project6]
                )  AS [Project7]
            )  AS [Project8]
        )  AS [Project9] ) AS [Project11]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) [Project12].[CommentId] AS [CommentId], [Project12].[CommentText] AS [CommentText], [Project12].[PostId] AS [PostId], [Project12].[CommentDate] AS [CommentDate], [Project12].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Project12].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent11].[CommentId] AS [CommentId], 
            [Extent11].[CommentText] AS [CommentText], 
            [Extent11].[PostId] AS [PostId], 
            [Extent11].[CommentDate] AS [CommentDate], 
            [Extent11].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
            [Extent11].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion]
            FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent11]
            WHERE [Project11].[PostId] = [Extent11].[PostId]
        )  AS [Project12]
        ORDER BY [Project12].[CommentDate] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
)  AS [Project13]
ORDER BY [Project13].[C3] DESC, [Project13].[PostId] ASC, [Project13].[Id] ASC, [Project13].[C2] ASC
```

Comment: I think 16 SELECT statements are too many... and what kind of generated query from LINQ looks then?

Comment: It depends on what SQL statements are generated since that would relate to the table relations you have. Isn't it? If you post those statements then it would be quicker to analyze, I guess.

Comment: Get an extract of the SQL queries you suspect this code of generating and post them up. I see a couple suspicious items but when optimizing EF it really is specific to the queries being run. A complex beast like this will likely *not* get down to a single query as several smaller queries may be far more efficient than 1 or 2 beasts to get a lot of loosely related details.

Answer (score 1):

First, it seems there is confusion between Linq and Linq to SQL. Not all of Linq can be translated into SQL queries. For example: `Any()` and `All()` can't be used with Linq to Sql here - they are in-memory collection functions. This means that all rows need to be fetched and then resolved afterwards.

You are also not resolving your first two queries, for example by calling `ToList()`.

```
var blockedusers = DataContext.BlockedUsers.Where(bu => bu.BlockerId == userId);
var followers = DataContext.FollowUser.Where(u => u.FollowFromUserId == userId);
```

This leaves them to run on-demand every time that they are used (deferred query execution) - meaning they call SQL each time. Beware the IEnumerable!

You could probably get rid of all your issues by doing joins onto BlockedUser and FollowUser all in the same query. For example, use a left join to BlockedUser and eliminate those rows by testing that the blocked user is null.

Comment: thanks, but how i can write my code instead of any & all

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should firstly orderby, skeep, take and then select new PostObject in return